# Сортировка маршрутов neo4j по свойству самого большого значения узла в маршруте

Tags: graph, neo4j

Имею довольно стандартный запрос в neo4j для поиска всех коротких маршрутов между двумя нодами.

```
MATCH 
     (object:Object { group: "12345" }), 
     (request:Request { group: "12345"}), 
     paths = allShortestPaths((request)-[*..12]->(object)) 
RETURN  
     paths
```

Стала задача отсортировать маршруты по наибольшему значению свойства ноды в каждом маршруте.

Допустим запрос возвращает три маршрута такого вида

```
 [{prop:1},{prop:2},{prop:4}],
 [{prop:1},{prop:2},{prop:3}],    
 [{prop:1},{prop:2},{prop:5}],
```

Задача вернуть маршруты по наибольшему значению свойства "prop" и получить маршруты в таком порядке

```
 [{prop:1},{prop:2},{prop:3}],    
 [{prop:1},{prop:2},{prop:4}],
 [{prop:1},{prop:2},{prop:5}],
```

Если кто то сталкивался, то дайте пожалуйста совет по решению задачи.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем сам смог реализовать запрос. Может кому пригодится для сортировки маршрутов по релевантности.

```
MATCH 
         (object:Object { group: "12345" }), 
         (request:Request { group: "12345"}), 
         paths = allShortestPaths((request)-[*..12]->(object)) 
WITH  
         paths, EXTRACT(x IN nodes(paths) | toInt(x.prop)) AS propsSort
UNWIND  
         propsSort as sort
RETURN  
         paths, max(sort) as sort
ORDER BY 
         sort DESC
```